# Javascript Regular Expressions - Replace non-numeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have this line:

```
val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')
```

and it replaces anything that is not a number, but I need a regular expression that limits `val` to be 2 numbers, period and then 2 numbers, like this:

```
- 11.33
- 12.34
- 54.65
```

I've already tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
val = val.replace(/^[^0-9\.]{1,2}/g, '')
```

Comment: What would happen to a number like `123.456`?

Comment: Why not just parse and then print with precision of 2 decimal places, after match, using replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with replace you scan the entire string and keep the middle part.  So start with beginning (^), scan some stuff you don't care about (.*), then scan your number ([0-9]{1,2}(?:.[0-9]{0-2})?), then scan the rest which you don't care about (.*), then you're at the end ($).

Then you replace with the middle capture group.

```
val.replace(/^(.*)([0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]{0-2})?)(.*)$/gm,'\2');
```

Use the m flag to process line by line.

Comment: The idea looks good, but there are issues with your code: 1.) If you use `.*` in first group it will consume anything up to the last digit, rather use lazy `.*?` 2.) The `{0-2}` quantifier should be `{0,2}` 3.) The replacement is rather `$2` than `\2` ([working demo](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/vywxR8FWQT0tP1/B0EjPwFghKbFI3ZqLCyIOJPWKUgtyEpNTNfTjNPS07DU1og10LWOrDXWMajXsrWL0IFwDIFcTKKmnpamin56ro65ipK4JNCY5P684PydVLyc/XQNomKb1//8A)).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to use multiple regexes instead of one. Here is a solution that uses a first regex to strip the string from anything but number digits, then a second regex that reduces the number string to the proper length:

```js
const regex1 = /[^\d\.]/g;
const regex2 = /^.*(\d\d\.\d\d).*$/;
[
  'aaa11.33zzz',
  'aaa123.456zzz',
  '-54.65',
  '12xtra.34'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = str.replace(regex1, '').replace(regex2, '$1');
  console.log(str, '==>', result);
});
```

Output:

```
aaa11.33zzz ==> 11.33
aaa123.456zzz ==> 23.45
-54.65 ==> 54.65
12xtra.34 ==> 12.34
```

Explanation of regex1:

- `[^\d\.]` -- anything not `0-9` and `.`
- `g` -- flag to replace pattern multiple times

Explanation of regex2:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `.*` -- greedy scan
- `(\d\d\.\d\d)` -- expect 2 digits, a dot, and 2 digits
- `.*` -- greedy scan
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

You did not specify what should happen if the input string has less than the 2digits, dot, 2 digits pattern. So this solution does not address that case.